# React application router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Navbar from './componants/Navbar';
import ProductList from './componants/ProductList';
import Details from './componants/Details';
import Default from './componants/Default';
import Cart from './componants/Cart';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path={'/'} Component={ProductList} />
         <Route path={'/Details'} Component={Details} />
         <Route path={'/Cart'} Component={Cart} />
         <Route Component={Default} />
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why `<switch></switch>` not working while I reach any page of my application?

Comment: Please be more specific about your question. What do you mean by "not working"? Error messages, screenshots, how does your `index.js` look like?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify like this

```
<Route exact path="/" component={PlaceOrder} />
<Route path="/updatepredicted" component={UpdatePredicted} />
<Route path="/kitchen" component={Kitchen} />
```

looks at the path